# Can I see a history of site index from Bing?

Tags: seo, web-hosting, security, bing, bing-webmaster-tools

I'm at a small internet company that has several apps. Our customers (all businesses) each have their own app-name/customer-name url. Currently, if you request a page preview from Bing's link preview service for one particular customer, the response includes an inappropriate image where our logo should be.

I am assuming this means our server was hacked, but we don't know when it happened. Is there any way to see the history of the index for this page? The page no longer gets indexed as it as now a redirect to an SSO login. But we need to find out when Bing found this image on our site.

And if you are asking "who uses bing page preview service?" the answer is outlook browser client. Our customer discovered this because they are all working from home and using the web client.

Comment: "I am assuming this means our server was hacked" -- or you were hotlinking the images.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the Internet Archive, also known as the "way back machine".  You can find it at https://archive.org/web/.  It's not Bing specific, but it does grab snapshots of websites and archive them over time.  You can use it to compare two different snapshot dates and then you'll have an idea of the date range changes occurred in.